# Recursively count the number of leaves in a binary tree without given parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am struggling to figure out how to code a recursive algorithm to count the number of leaves in a Binary Tree (not a complete tree). I get as far as traversing to the far most left leaf and don't know what to return from there. I am trying to get the count by loading the leaves into a list and getting the size of that list. This is probably a bad way to go about the count.

```
    public int countLeaves ( ) {

    List< Node<E> > leafList = new ArrayList< Node<E> >();
    //BinaryTree<Node<E>> treeList = new BinaryTree(root);

    if(root.left != null) 
    {
        root = root.left;
        countLeaves();
    }
    if(root.right != null) 
    {
        root = root.right;
        countLeaves();
    }
    if(root.left == null && root.right == null) 
    {
        leafList.add(root);
    }


        return();
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want to change your root node just to count your leave numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on @dasblinkenlight idea. You want to recursively call a  countleaves on root node & pass back the # to caller. Something on the following lines.

```
public int countLeaves() {
 return countLeaves(root);
 }

/**
 * Recursively count all nodes
 */
private static int countLeaves (Node<E> node) {
 if(node==null)
   return 0;

 if(node.left ==null && node.right == null)
  return 1;
 else {
    return countLeaves(node.left) + countLeaves(node.right);
   }
}
```

Edit: It appears, a similar problem was previously asked [counting number of leaf nodes in binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949882/counting-number-of-leaf-nodes-in-binary-tree)

Comment: don't you think it's too verbose? there should only be 2 `if`s.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, Thanks for pointing that out. It was definitely very verbose. I edited per your suggestion.

Comment: in fact, since you allow an null node to pass in, the branching of this problem should be able to be reduced to that null check only. also your else case is wrong. missing a `1`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, Now since we want to only count leaves, the only time i would want to count, +1, should be when node.left & node.right are null right?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I thought it was too count the number of nodes.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, I had made that mistake in my first implementation. Thanks to you for pointing out & helping me correct it.

Comment: Ah, so in essence I want to implement a recursive helper method to create  a parameter?

Comment: @ekim6755, Right in my sample implementation am recursively calculating leaves in a helper method. Now, you can instead call one method i.e. `private static int countLeaves (Node<E> node)` directly and that will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that it does not restore the value of member variable `root` back to the state that it had prior to entering the method. You could do it by storing the value in a local variable, i.e.

```
Node<E> oldRoot = root;
... // your method goes here
root = oldRoot;
```

However, a better approach is to take `Node<E>` as an argument, rather than relying on a shared variable:

```
public int countLeaves() {
    return countLeaves(root);
}

private static int countLeaves (Node<E> node) {
    ... // Do counting here
}
```